# Loader requireJs doesn't respect dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependencies, requirejs, typescript, pixi.js

I use requireJs to load my javascript files.
I import the lib pixi.js and pixi_extends.js, but pixi_extends generate an error because PIXI is undefined... I don't understand because pixi_extends should wait that pixi.js is uploaded before run.

It's the same with the Bundle, same error about pixi.

I don't understant, I did the "deps" correctly I assume!

*loader-index.**ts**:* (I use TypeScript!)

```
/// <reference path="../def/require.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="Init.class.ts" />

/**
 * paths    List of the files to load. (Cannot contains references TS classes)
 *              key: New reference name of the file.
 *              path: Relative path to /public/js/ of the file.
 *
 * shim     Config about the libraries (dependencies and more).
 *          See http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim
 */
require.config({
    //urlArgs: "t=" +  (new Date()).getTime(),
    //baseUrl: "../",
    paths: {
        /*
         ******** Load libraries ********
         */
        // Lib - jQuery
        'jquery': '../generated/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        'jqueryUiCore': '../generated/lib/jquery.ui.core.min',
        'jqueryUiEffect': '../generated/lib/jquery.ui.effect.min',

        // Lib - Javascript extends
        'class': '../generated/lib/class.min',

        // Lib - Pixi
        'pixi': '../generated/lib/pixi.min',
        'pixiExtends': '../generated/lib/pixi_extends.min',

        // Lib - Socket
        'socketIo': '../generated/lib/socket.io.min',

        // Lib - Pomelo
        'pomeloclient': '../generated/lib/pomeloclient.min',

        // Lib - Path finder
        'aStar': '../generated/lib/AStar.min',

        /*
         ******** Load shared source code ********
         */
        'Message': '../generated/shared/Message.min',
        'ValidatorMessage': '../generated/shared/ValidatorMessage.min',

        /*
         ******** Load other scripts ********
         */
        'bundle': '../generated/bundle.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'jqueryUiCore': {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: '$'
        },
        'jqueryUiEffect': {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "$"
        },
        'pixiExtends': {
            deps: ["jquery", "pixi"]
        },
        'pomeloclient': {
            deps: ["socketIo"]
        },
        'ValidatorMessage': {
            deps: ["Message"]
        },
        'bundle': {
            deps: ["pixi", "pixiExtends", "pomeloclient"]
        }
    }
});


/**
 * [] Array of name that should be the same than those defined in the config.paths. Exception for the TS classes with reference in this file.
 */
require(
    [
        'Init.class',
        'jquery', 'jqueryUiCore', 'jqueryUiEffect',
        'class',
        'pixi', 'pixiExtends',
        'socketIo', 'pomeloclient',
        'aStar',
        'Message', 'ValidatorMessage',
        'bundle'
    ],
    (
        _init,
         $, jqueryUiCore, jqueryUiEffect,
         _class,
         _pixi, pixiExtends,
         _socketIo, _pomeloclient,
         _aStar,
         _message, _validatorMessage,
         _bundle
    )
    => {
        // Initialization.
        var init = new _init.Init();

        // Make shared source classes public, to help.
        _exports([
            _message.Message,
            _validatorMessage.ValidatorMessage
        ]);


        /**
         * Export an array of object to made them public on the browser.
         * @param   objects - Array of objects. Class of function basically.
         * @private
         */
        function _exports(objects){
            for(var i in objects){
                _export(objects[i]);
            }
        }

        /**
         *Export an object to the browser to make it public.
         * @param o     Object to export.
         * @param name  Customise the name. Optional.
         * @private
         */
        function _export(o: any, name: any = ''){
            if(!name){
                name = o.name;
            }
            window[name] = o;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I fixed it with add windows['PIXI'] = PIXI in the pixi.js script. Maybe it's the way to export it which is not good with requireJs.

Comment: Pixi.js script: (12k lines) http://pastebin.com/SV0XLyq6

Comment: I think I know why it doesn't respect the dependencies! It's because my pixi.js script doesn't exports itself with the define() function. I think there is a way to auto use define() when load scripts who are not exporting themself by this way, I've to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be enough to add the following entry to the `shim` section:

```
'pixi': {
  exports: 'PIXI'
}
```

This turns this library into an AMD-compatibile module which can be used as a standalone dependency, also in the `deps` section of other shims.

**Edit:**

Reading your comments seems that this "pixi_extends" module is your own code; you're **not** supposed to `shim` your own modules, it's only meant to be used for legacy non-AMD libraries. If you want to augment Pixi with your customisations, do something like this:

```
define(['pixi'], function (ThePixiObject) {
  ThePixiObject.customFunction = function () {
    console.log('Pixi now has customFunction()');
  }

  // no need to return anything - we're only interested in the side-effect above
});
```

Recommended: [official documentation regarding shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)

---

*NB. Also, there's no need to configure shim for jQuery, it's already AMD compatibile.*

Comment: I retried just right now and I'm right, it's not working. The exports in the shim don't do anything. No changes.

Comment: Created a simplistic project to prove that pixi can be correctly shimmed and works OK: https://github.com/kryger/stackoverflow_20295954.

Comment: It was because I didn't understand completely the way the require() function works, now it's okay! I thought the config was enough but it was not, I needed to require pixi using the code from @kryger. Took some time to understand everything ;)

Comment: Glad to help - I found that learning RequireJS was much easier with simplified mini-projects. In project of your size there are simply too many things that can go wrong, this makes finding the problem more difficult.

Comment: Yes, you're right, especially a lot of dependies, I'm dealing with almost two hundreds classes here. Many are merged on the same file, hopefully. What I posted here is just the basics dependencies, the libraries actually. Now I've implemented something really strong and had to deal with the domLoader addong and more... Takes time! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with using the require() function in the pixi_extends and removing my changes from the official pixi.js lib. Now that works.

But the exports with requirejs doesn't have any effect, I don't get it. That should export in global the PIXI value, it's what that should do and that doesn't work.

I can export it manually once everything is loaded, it's a solution if I wanted to have PIXI as global. But I don't absolutely need it so I'll keep in this way.

But I would like to understand why the "shim exports" doesn't works.